# How do I get Friday date if it is Monday today

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have .Net project for some reason i need to have date to be taken.

I have done like 
`var date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);`
which is giving me `yesterday's` date.
but if I run my application on `Monday` then I should get `Friday` date

please suggest me expression for this.

for example.
if today is `Monday` and date is `21/12/2001` it should give me `19/12/2001` i.e `Fridays` date
if today is `Tuesday` and date is`21/12/2001` it should return me `20/12/2001` as normal

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the `DateTime` class and the methods it provides?

Comment: Not at all clear what you want here.  Do you want the previous working day? E.G if it's monday, you want the previous friday, if tuesday then monday, weds then tues and so on?

Comment: > but if I run my application on Monday then I should get Friday date There's a built-in assumption here: You don't want weekends, so perhaps you're interested in using a business calendar for calculations; only workdays. Is that correct? If yes, I'd wonder if you also need to include holidays into it as well. If you happen to run this on the Monday after a three-day weekend, are you expecting to get Thursday back?

Comment: Yes all i want previous working day.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
public DateTime GetPreviousWorkingDay(DateTime date)
{
    switch(date.DayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            return date.AddDays(-2);
        case DayOfWeek.Monday:
            return date.AddDays(-3);
        default:
            return date.AddDays(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, I did something similar  but forgot about Sundays :) All I would suggest is that this is probably well suited to be an extension method on DateTime.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Check if the date is a sunday, if so deduct three days instead
if(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3)
```

Comment: Monday, Monday. Other than that, I think the answer is correct.

Comment: If today -1 is sunday then today -3 is friday

Comment: Ah, you are correcting the previously obtained result. Ok but maybe it could be made simpler, checking always from DateTime.Today.

Comment: Yes, go for Rik's answer for a more robust function.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday ? DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3) : DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: The original question was if it's Monday I need Friday; which is what this will give.  However, the requirement changed and @Rik gave the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the previous working day as per my comment above:

```
    public static DateTime GetPreviousWorkingDay(DateTime fromDate)
    {
        while ((fromDate=(fromDate.Date - TimeSpan.FromDays(1))).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday | fromDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {}

        return fromDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime lastWorkingDay;
        if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) 
        {
            lastWorkingDay = today.AddDays(-3);
        }
        else
        {
            lastWorkingDay = today.AddDays(-1);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(lastWorkingDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Riks answer, if you also need to handle national holidays:

```
private Date[] _publicHolidays = { new Date(2011, 12, 25) };

public Date GetPreviousWorkingDay(Date date) 
{ 
    Date previousDay;

    switch(date.DayOfWeek) 
    { 
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday: 
            previousDay = date.AddDays(-2); 
        case DayOfWeek.Monday: 
            previousDay = date.AddDays(-3); 
        default: 
            previousDay = date.AddDays(-1); 
    } 

    if (_publicHolidays.Contains(previousDay))
   {
      return GetPreviousWorkingDay(previousDay);
   }
}
```

How you populate your list of public holidays is really down to you...